# Not able to erase from input buffer when the line wraps (pexpect)

Tags: python, expect, paramiko, pexpect, pxssh

I am using a script to connect to another server. The skeleton looks something like this:

```
import pexpect
...
child = pexpect.spawn(f"""ssh {username}@{host}""")
child.setwinsize(136,1000)
child.expect("Password:")
child.sendline(pwd)
```

However, when I enter a very long input it wraps around to the next line. The problem I am facing is that when I try to erase it (backspace-it), it doesn't take me to the previous line. So the input stays as is on the previous line. But this is how it is shown to me in the terminal, behind the scene the input gets backspaced (if that's a word).

Comment: i did not see how you "enter a very long input" in the question.

Comment: Do you really need to automate an interactive session? Why not use paramiko?

Comment: I am not quite sure of what `paramiko` offers. My use case is, I have to login to multiple bastion hosts. Each of them require a lot of passwords, MFAs. I want to automate that part, and once that's done. I want the terminal to become interactive so that I can execute more commands.

Comment: By `multiple bastion hosts` I mean multiple hops.